# R: Can I include an R markdown file in a shiny ui.R file?

Tags: r, shiny, knitr

I refer to the code example at http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/including-html-text-and-markdown-files.html. In my case I would like to include and R markdown file rather than a markdown.

The following is my code for ui.R

```
library(markdown)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Tourist expenditure for the year 2012 in Malta"),

    fluidRow(
        column(2,
               checkboxGroupInput("id1", "Analyse by",
                                  c("Sex" = "1",
                                    "Age Group" = "2")
         )),
        column(6,
               h4('You entered'),
               verbatimTextOutput("oid1")
        ),
        column(4,
               includeMarkdown("intro.Rmd")
        )
    )
))
```

My problem is that intro.Rmd is not compiling when embedded in shinyUI but works as expected when I choose the Knit HTML option.

Is there a way I can insert the Rmd source file directly.

Thanks.

Comment: Try changing it to `intro.md`.

Comment: Are you getting an error or are you getting blank? Are you sure it's in the right folder?

Comment: @Elin: when I renamed the **.Rmd** to **.md** I got the uncompiled source.

When I included the output from the Knitr (index.html) I get the correct result but get an annoying **<!DOCTYPE html>** tag. Tou can view the output of the project at https://chribonn.shinyapps.io/devdataprod-016/.

Thanks.

Comment: Update: After specifying the yaml instruction **keep_md: yes**, the recommendation by @Elin works. I still believe that the best solution would be to have shiny be able to parse the .Rmd as this is the source that gets modified each time.

Comment: If that file is getting modified each time you should use `rmarkdown::render("myfile.Rmd")` and wrap the include around that, but I also don't thing including it as if it is a static file makes the most sense in that case.  I think architecturally it probably makes more sense to do the `rmarkdown::render("myfile.Rmd")` on the server side.

Comment: @Elin: Am I correct in understanding that rather than type     `includeMarkdown("intro.Rmd")` I type     `includeMarkdown(rmarkdown::render("intro.Rmd"))`?  I'll give it a try later on and report back. 

My only question is how would the program know what file to include. Maybe when I try it the answer will be obvious.

Comment: How is it knowing now? If you have to generate the name as a variable you have to use that. Also if have generated the markdown string server side then you can just include that on the ui side.

Comment: @Erin: Your suggestion worked perfectly - thank you.

Apologies if I appear thick headed but how does the includeMarkdown know what content to include. When I type `rmarkdown::render("intro.Rmd")` into RStudio what I get is the page compilation process (during which two files are created the **.md** and the **.html**).

How does the `includeMarkdown` function know which file to pick up (given that no parameter is passed to it and the output from rmarkdown::render is not the page itself.

This is what baffled me.

Answer (score 9):

I've had similar problems in the past, and know of two solutions:

1. pre-compile the .Rmd file and include the markdown or HTML using the functions you've mentioned.
2. call knitr from shiny within the server.R file (if the document changes due to the shiny app) and then include the compiled HTML/markdown code with includeHTML() or a similar function.

Comment: I did 2nd option, but datatables does not render tables in compiled HTML in Shiny when I use `includeHTML() ` , but in web browser it works. Can you help?

Comment: Do you mean that datatables doesn't render the html in the preview window but does when you view the app in a browser? If so, I'd call that a success. RStudio's preview browser doesn't always handle custom CSS and Javascript correctly.