# Problems with adding formula to Markdown in Shiny

Tags: shiny

I want to add text in a tabPanel which contains some formula. The ui looks like this:

```
library(markdown)
library(shiny) 

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          ),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel('Text', includeMarkdown("post.rmd"))
        )

      )
    )
  )
)
```

And the markdown file looks like this:

```html
This  is a text test.

### Equations
There are inline equations such as $y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + e_i$.

And displayed formulas:

$$\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}$$
```

When I run this, I do not get the formula as wanted but like texted as above.
I have followed the instruction from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397089/r-can-i-include-an-r-markdown-file-in-a-shiny-ui-r-file)

and changed the format to .md but it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In a linked discussion there are comments about rendering rmarkdown files. R shiny doesn't automatically render markdown file as html so you have to add: `rmarkdown::render("post.Rmd")`. You could also compile your markdown file beforehand as html and use `includeHtml` in that case just use code: `includeHTML(("post.html"))`

```
library(markdown)
library(shiny) 
server <- function(input, output) {

}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

    ),
    mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel('Text', includeMarkdown(rmarkdown::render("post.rmd")))
        )

    )
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: great both ways work, although with the first solution I still get a `<!DOCTYPE html>`which I can not get rid of.

Comment: Thank you for this help. If I add a slider the slider get messed up. I have posted this problem here:[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580760/reactive-slider-in-shiny-and-rendering-a-html-file-does-not-work-together)