# reactive Slider in Shiny and rendering a html file does not work together

Tags: shiny

I would like to use tabPanels and have a problem with the combination of a reactive Slider and including a html file in ui.R. It seems that this problem is not due to tabPanel and also shows up when I put it all with `includeX` in the mainPanel.

If I do this like shown here I get Panel text with formulas rendered right, but the slider is messed up.
If the text is included as rmd ( or as md ) the slider is shown right, but the formulas are not rendered right.

I have posted a similar, but slightly different question here at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557122/problems-with-adding-formula-to-markdown-in-shiny), these question may have the same reason, but I am not sure.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$first <- renderUI({
    sliderInput('xScale', '', 
                min=7.0,max=9.0, value=c(7.5, 8.5), step=0.01)
  })

session$onSessionEnded(function() {
        stopApp()
    })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          uiOutput('first')
        ),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel('Text', includeHTML("post.html"))
        #tabPanel('Text', includeMarkdown('post.rmd'))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is a bug. Maybe write bug report to [Shiny issues](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues) or try to find answer from official forum.

Comment: @Mikael Thank you, I have reported this on Github.